# Deployed static website to Azure via terraform - but the blade is inaccessible with permission error?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I've got a very basic terraform deployment going through Azure Devops, which defines a storage bucket and static website. However, when I go into the Azure Portal, the static website blade gives me "Access Denied. You do not have access". All other aspects of the storage bucket are available, though, so it doesn't appear to be a general permissions issue.

Terraform doesn't support the config in the AZ RM, so I'm using the local-exec pattern to configure the static website.

Running in DevOps, my terraform has a system connection and runs as a service user. However, I've also tried destroying the bucket and re-running the terraform as my user - this doesn't make any difference.

I've tried adding myself onto the IAM on the bucket, that also doesn't make any difference.

The definition for the storage bucket is:

```
  name                     = "website"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.prod.name}"
  location                 = var.region
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    # https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1903
    command = "az storage blob service-properties update --account-name ${azurerm_storage_account.website-storage.name} --static-website --index-document index.html --404-document 404.html"
  }
}
```

I'm expecting to be able to get to the static website blade within the Portal - is there some reason why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't yet have a reason why this happened. I had earlier tried removing the storage and re-creating, but I removed the storage via the portal. This evening I tried renaming the resource in Terraform which forced it to destroy and recreate, and that works.

I had previously messed about with StorageV1 resource / container / blob definition of the same name; potentially there was something "invisible" in Azure which was causing this oddness...

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could Accept it as an Answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem. Created a storage account for blob storage, couldn't see "static website" in the menu, deleted it and made a general purpose v2 storage account *with the same name*, and can see it in the menu, but get access denied. Recreated with a new name and it worked.